# SSH Tunneling to docker container

Tags: linux, ssh, docker, virtual-machine, ssh-tunnel

I'm trying to establish an ssh tunnel to my docker container running on my remote Virtual Server.

Basically I followed the instruction here on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28134239/how-to-ssh-into-docker) where you also find more details about what I'm trying to achieve:

Stackoverflow's linked post: [How to SSH into Docker?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28134239/how-to-ssh-into-docker)

Actually I set up everything correctly but my connection is terminated every time with the following message:

---

```
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
@ WARNING: REMOTE HOST IDENTIFICATION HAS CHANGED! @
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
IT IS POSSIBLE THAT SOMEONE IS DOING SOMETHING NASTY!
Someone could be eavesdropping on you right now (man-in-the-middle attack)!
It is also possible that a host key has just been changed.
The fingerprint for the RSA key sent by the remote host is <rsa-key>.
Please contact your system administrator.
Add correct host key in /home/rico/.ssh/known_hosts to get rid of this message.
Offending ECDSA key in /home/rico/.ssh/known_hosts:31 remove with: ssh-keygen -f "/home/rico/.ssh/known_hosts" -R [<server-ip>]:33
RSA host key for [<server-ip>]:33 has changed and you have requested strict checking.
Host key verification failed.
```

---

I attached a screenshot here: 
https://s18.postimg.org/ivnnxj7a1/connection_closed.png

My command line is:

`ssh -p 33 root@<server-ip>`

where '33' is the ssh port of the docker container.

What I have to do in order to have the connection accepted by my Virtual Server?

**[UPDATE]**

run the command adding also -v flag and post the output:

```
OpenSSH_6.6.1, OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to <server-ip> [<server-ip>] port 44.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/rico/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: identity file /home/rico/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/rico/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/rico/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/rico/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/rico/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/rico/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /home/rico/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2.8
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.7p1 Debian-5+deb8u3
debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.7p1 Debian-5+deb8u3 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com none
debug1: sending SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_INIT
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ECDSA <server-mac-address>
debug1: Host '[<server-ip>]:44' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/rico/.ssh/known_hosts:32
debug1: ssh_ecdsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/rico/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Offering RSA public key: <my-email>@gmail.com
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Offering RSA public key: <my-email>@gmail.com
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Trying private key: /home/rico/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/rico/.ssh/id_ecdsa 
debug1: Trying private key: /home/rico/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: Next authentication method: password
root@<server-ip>'s password:
```

Even if I set up a new root password it doesn't work

Answer (score 4):

You might want to reconsider using SSH. As the comments in your [linked post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28134239/how-to-ssh-into-docker) point out, this goes against Docker's concept. Furthermore, running addtional SSH server(s) increases your potential attack surface.

There are two alternatives for getting access to your containers:

1. SSH into your VM and use `docker exec`, e.g. `docker exec -it <yourcontainer> bash`
2. Connect your local client to the docker daemon running inside your VM. This is an advanced approach, but Docker has a [good documentation](https://docs.docker.com/v1.10/engine/reference/commandline/daemon/#daemon-socket-option) how to do it [securely](https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/https/). In a nuthshell: You configure the daemon on your VM to listen to a TCP socket, e.g. `dockerd -H=0.0.0.0:2376`. Then you point your local client to the corresponding IP, `docker -H=$HOST:2376 version`. Everyting **must be secured** by using signed TLS certificates.

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

You can *bypass* that issue by adding this to your `ssh` command:

```
-o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no
```

To solve the authentication problem, follow this [guide](http://sshkeychain.sourceforge.net/mirrors/SSH-with-Keys-HOWTO/SSH-with-Keys-HOWTO-4.html) to create an `authorized_keys` file and finally add it to your image using the `Dockerfile`:

```
ADD authorized_keys /home/docker/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

**NOTE**: as @stepf comments `ssh` is not intended way to access docker containers.

Comment: It partially worked. The message is gone, but it doesn't let me in. In fact it asks for a password. I set a password on both the virtual server and docker but no one works. What else can I do?